# Where to ask NXP LPC1343 / ARM Cortex M3 related questions

Tags: microcontroller, embedded-systems, arm-cpu

I am a beginner to robotics and embedded systems. Consequently I have a lot of questions related to the toolchain and how things are going together like how to debug or how to connect a bluetooth module.

I already tried https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ and it did not work out for me.

Any ideas where I can get help with my LPC1343 related questions?

Comment: Could you flag your question on electronics.stackexchange and have it migrated here?

Comment: Toolchain questions are not really on-topic here, @Ian

Comment: You could try stackoverflow,or wait another few months for embeddedsystems.se to reach public beta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel that people who say "this is off-topic" should [tell you about some other place where that is on-topic](http://communitywiki.org/en/OnAndOffTopic).

- I see that you and I are not the only people who think the electronics stackexchange is a good place to ask questions about the [NXP LPC1343](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=LPC1343) and other [ARM Cortex M3](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=Cortex%20M3) processors.
- The Arduino Due uses a ARM Cortex-M3 CPU -- perhaps the [Arduino Forum](http://forum.arduino.cc/) or the [Arduino Stackexchange](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/) or the [Arduino Playground](http://playground.arduino.cc/) might be a good place to ask about setting up a toolchain and debugger for the M3 and other things that are not hyper-specific to the LPC1343.
- the [GCC ARM Improvement Project](http://www.inf.u-szeged.hu/gcc-arm/) might be a good place to ask about setting up a toolchain and debugger that is not specificic to the M3.
- The [lpc13xx Microprocessor Forum](http://www.lpcware.com/forums/microprocessor-forums/lpc13xx) may be a good place to ask about things that are specific to the LPC13xx series (including the LPC1343).
- The LPCXpresso now uses the LPC1347 chip -- perhaps you might pick up some good tips at the [LPCXpresso Forum](http://www.lpcware.com/forums/lpcxpresso/lpcxpresso-forum)
- Perhaps you might pick up some good tips in the "Getting started with the [LPC-P1343](https://www.olimex.com/Products/ARM/NXP/LPC-P1343/)" document.
- I hear the [Dangerous Prototypes forum sometimes discusses the LPC1343](http://dangerousprototypes.com/forum/search.php?keywords=LPC1343&submit=Search).

Good luck.